# can't connect android app to mysql using php the error is with my android code

Tags: php, android

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;



import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class login extends Activity {
Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
EditText breakfast= (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.breakfast) ;
        EditText lunch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lunch);
        EditText dinner = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dinner);
        EditText supper = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.supper);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;

        final String breakf = breakfast.getText().toString();
        final String lun = lunch.getText().toString();
        final String din = dinner.getText().toString();
        final String sup = supper.getText().toString();
button2=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // generate your params:
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("breakfast", breakf));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lunch", lun));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Dinner", din));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("supper", sup));

   // send them on their way
   try {
       DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://blahblah php?$username=caroline$password=scamper");
```

i have a proper url for their i just blanked  it out

```
      // httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValueParams));

       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}});}
//@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
finish();
System.exit(0);
}
});
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, .class);
Login.this.startActivity(intent);
//new lister for save start db code their
//take info from button with sql




   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       postData();
});

   //
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}
```

i know i have some errors in it but i have been changeig it and can't figure  why it won't change any help would be greatly appreiciated the php should work i am not getting any info from app

Comment: You should move your code where you are attempting networking into background Thread. Generall y you shouldn't peform networking on Main(UI) thread(from Android 3.0 it's totally prohibited).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't invoke network connections in the main thread. Try using AsyncTask in order to run the network operations on the background thread.

Try like this

```
Class Login extends Activity
{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
     button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
     {
       public void onClick(View arg0) 
       {
         Task t = new Task();
         t.execute();
       }
   }
   class Task extends AsyncTask<ArgType,ArgType,ArgType>
   {
     protected type doInBackground(ArgType... urls) 
     {
       try
       {
          //initiate httpconnection and get result
       }
       catch
       {
       }
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(ArgType result) 
     {
       //update some view or do some thing when background thread work is done
     }
   }
}
```

Or you can refer to http://www.android-ever.com/2012/10/android-asynctask-example.html for more information on AsyncTask.